# androidMainifest activity attributes not working in qt-android

Tags: android, qt

I'm using qt framework to develop an android application, We know that by adding `android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustPan"` in androidmainifest.xml under activity tag we can prevent resizing window when displaying the virtual keyboard. But in Qt it not working!

can anyone help me to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have added android:windowSoftInputMode inside the activity tag, then please check the following solution

```
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnchanged|adjustPan"
```

taken from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/11454337/1739677

Comment: I tried it before ask question , not working in qt :(

Comment: can you provide us with more of your source code please, manifest and the activity class that you want to add the windowSoftInputMode