# Push only the bottom part up when Soft keyboard appears

Tags: android, layout, android-edittext, scrollview, android-softkeyboard

The only thing I am trying do that there will be an editText at the top and after that there will be an ImageView.
Now at the bottom line there will be some buttons (ex. emojis) and this bottom part will only be pushed up by the soft keyboard whenever it will appear.

I am making it more clear by attaching this layout of Facebook.
[required output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXCNT.png)

I have gone through all these SO questions and also tried their answers but no luck. May be I am doing something wrong.

[Android: Resize only parts of view with soft keyboard on screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21201569/android-resize-only-parts-of-view-with-soft-keyboard-on-screen)

[Android: How do I prevent the soft keyboard from pushing my view up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4207880/android-how-do-i-prevent-the-soft-keyboard-from-pushing-my-view-up)

[android : How to prevent resizing the window when displaying the virtual keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5180789/android-how-to-prevent-resizing-the-window-when-displaying-the-virtual-keyboar)

My XML code

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollOnPost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:isScrollContainer="false"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/header_layout">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom">
 <EditText
            android:id="@+id/ed_post"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_posted_list_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.7"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/red"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imgBtn_Emoji"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:src="@drawable/smile_face"
    android:background="@drawable/button_pressed_white"
    />
```

All I getting that my soft keyboard always pushing the whole layout up not just the emoji at the bottom. Thanks.

Comment: see this link it may help you : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17410499/difference-between-adjustresize-and-adjustpan-in-android

Comment: Thanks for the link Kunal. I have tried both "adjustResize" , "adjustPan" and also both together  at the manifest but result is not what I need. But the question is exact same problem I have. thanks again.

Comment: @ Md. Asaduzzaman Noor il try adding your layout in my code and c what solution i can find

Comment: Ok just wrap my whole code into a RelativeLayout and put any keyboard mode you want to test in your manifest.

Comment: did you check it? if it helped you please mark it as the answer and upvote it

Comment: i have changed my answer please check it.

Answer (score 0):

Dude it worked
manifest :

```
<activity android:name=".TestActivity"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"/>
```

xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollOnPost"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:isScrollContainer="false"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:layout_below="@+id/header_layout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:gravity="bottom">
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/ed_post"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_posted_list_row"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="2.7"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>
    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/imgBtn_Emoji"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/call"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

I guess you want only the editText to push up when keyboard is visible(Correct me if i am wrong) for that i have got an idea i don't know if it will work or not you can try it out if you find it logical

Idea is to first check if keyboard is visible or not and secondly if visible get its height and programatically give your layout a marginBottom which will be equal to the height of keyboard(using layoutParams).

check this links for implementing above idea :

[How to capture the "virtual keyboard show/hide" event in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312319/how-to-capture-the-virtual-keyboard-show-hide-event-in-android)

[Is there any way in android to get the height of virtual keyboard of device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788959/is-there-any-way-in-android-to-get-the-height-of-virtual-keyboard-of-device)

[How to set RelativeLayout layout params in code not in xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191099/how-to-set-relativelayout-layout-params-in-code-not-in-xml)

[image: before clicking edit text]

[image: after clicking edit text]

Comment: Thanks that you have tried to help @Kunal but its not working, Please take a look into the attached image and try to understand clearly my requirement.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Kunal but I got that idea long time ago and also tried that. But it does not work perfectly for all kind of devices and ofcourse it is not the best practice. I just want to know the same way facebook do that. thats it.